# Need help using Atan2 instead Arctan for transforming cartesian to polar coordinates.

Tags: trigonometry

I need some help to use Atan2 function instead of arctan to the following equation. This is used to find the inverse of lon, lat angles based on a lon lat reference point projected onto an x,y plane in orthographic map projection.

The equation using arctan is given on the Wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection_in_cartography):

$$ \lambda = \lambda_0 +\arctan \left( \frac {x \sin c}{\rho \cos \varphi_0 \cos c - y \sin \varphi_0 \sin c } \right) $$ 
Can anyone show me how this equation would look using atan2? I'm pretty math dense and don't understand how to use or implement atan2.

Note:
$\lambda $ is the longitude. $\lambda_0 $ is the reference longitude and $ \varphi_0 $  is the reference latitude corresponding to the x,y origin on a projected plane. c is given as $ c=arcsin \left( \frac {\rho}{R} \right) $ where $ R $ is the radius of the earth, and $ \rho = \sqrt{x^2+y^2 }$

Comment: Here is the equation in C# using arctan: 
`lon=lon0 + Math.Atan((x*Math.Sin(c))/(p*Math.Cos(lat0)*Math.Cos(c)-y*Math.Sin (lat0)*Math.Sin (c)));` I just need to know how to rewrite this for atan2 function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is usually defined as `atan2(y,x)` which returns $\tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x}$, but with the right sign depending on the quadrant. You almost always take your expression and feed the numerator as $y$ and the denominator as $x$. So you would have

$$ \lambda = \lambda_0 +\operatorname{atan2} \left( x \sin c, \, \rho \cos \varphi_0 \cos c - y \sin \varphi_0 \sin c  \right) $$